# Script to scan computers from a list and identify which ones have a software title installed

Tags: powershell

I have narrowed down a little more what exactly my end game is.

I have pre-created the file that I want the results to write to.

Here is a rough script of what I want to do:

```
$computers = Get-content "C:\users\nicholas.j.nedrow\desktop\scripts\lists\ComputerList.txt"

# Ping all computers in ComputerList.txt.  
# Need WinEst_Computers.csv file created with 3 Columns; Computer Name | Online (Y/N) | Does File Exist (Y/N)

$output = foreach ($comp in $computers) {
    $TestConn = Test-connection -cn $comp -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet
    if ($TestConn -match "False")
    {
    #Write "N" to "Online (Y/N)" Column in primary output .csv file 
    }
    if ($TestConn -match "True")
    {
    #Write "Y" to "Online (Y/N)" Column in primary output .csv file
    }

#For computers that return a "True" ping value:
#Search for WinEst.exe application on C:\
    Get-ChildItem -Path "\\$comp\c$\program files (x86)\WinEst.exe" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
        if ("\\$comp\c$\program files (x86)\WinEst.exe" -match "False")
        {
        #Write "N" to "Does File Exist (Y/N)" Column in primary output .csv file    
        }
        if ("\\$comp\c$\program files (x86)\WinEst.exe" -match "True")
        {
        #Write "Y" to "Does File Exist (Y/N)" Column in primary output .csv file
        }
        Select @{n='ComputerName';e={$comp}},Name
}


$output | Out-file "C:\users\nicholas.j.nedrow\desktop\scripts\results\CSV Files\WinEst_Computers.csv"
```

What I need help with is the following:

1. How to get each result to either write to the appropriate line (I.e. computername, online, file exist?) or would it be easier to do one column at a time;

--Write all PC's to Column A
--Ping each machine and record results in Column B
--Search each machine for the .exe and record results.

Any suggestions?  Sorry I keep changing things.  Just trying to figure out the best way to do this.

Comment: you have not told the `Export-Csv` cmdlet _what to export_ ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

You are using the [foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7.1) command, which has a syntax `foreach ($itemVariable in $collectionVariable) { }`. If `$computer` is your collection, then your current item cannot also be `$computer` inside your `foreach`.

`Get-Item` does not return a property `computerName`. Therefore you cannot explicitly select it with `Select-Object`. However, you can use a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.1#example-10--create-calculated-properties-for-each-inputobject) to add a new property to the custom object that [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.1) outputs.

If your CSV file has a row of header(s), it is simpler to use `Import-Csv` to read the file. If it is just a list of computer names, then `Get-Content` works well.

If you are searching for a single file and you know the exact path, then just stick with `-Path` or `-LiteralPath` and forget `-Include`. `-Include` is not intuitive and isn't explained well in the online documentation.

If you are piping output to `Export-Csv` using a single pipeline, there's no need for `-Append` unless you already have an existing CSV with data you want to retain. However, if you choose to pipe to `Export-Csv` during each loop iteration, `-Append` would be necessary to retain the output.

Here is some updated code using the recommendations:

```
$computers = Get-content "C:\users\nicholas.j.nedrow\desktop\scripts\lists\ComputerList.txt"
$output = foreach ($comp in $computers) {
    Get-Item -Path "\\$comp\c$\program files (x86)\WinEst.exe" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
        Select @{n='ComputerName';e={$comp}},Name
}
$output | Export-Csv -Path "C:\users\nicholas.j.nedrow\desktop\scripts\results\CSV Files\WinEst_Computers.csv" -NoType
```

Comment: Running the suggestions now.  Will update soon.  Thanks for the assist!

Comment: Looks like it ran with no errors but the export file has no information in it.  I am assuming that means that I am not piping the output correctly?